# How to create real static property in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I hava an A.java file ->
`class A{ public static Integer age = 30;}`

and hava a B.java file -> `print(A.age)`

but when I convert A.java to A.kt it does't work by **object** or **companion** keyworld.

if I use **object** I must change it to `print(A.INSTANCE.age)`
and if I use **companion** I must change it to `print(A.Companion.age)` , but I can't change B.java file in some condition , So what can I do for it?

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer or tell me what else do you need that is missing in my answer...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
class A {
  companion object {
    @JvmField var age = 114514
  }
}
```

Or simply

```
object A {
  @JvmField var age = 114514
}
```

Both codes above will create a `public static int` member for class `A`.

According to the comment, to avoid creating an object, you may make use of file-scope variables.

```
// A.kt
@file:JvmName("A")
package your.pkg

@JvmField var age = 114514
```

And you can access this `public static int age` via `A.age` in Java.

Comment: thank you very much , It is highly similar by these ways，but actually it has some different with java，because all of these have create an object，but it has't create any object in java language.


So,can you have better suggestions？

Comment: Yes. You may combine my answer with Dominik's. See the update

Comment: right! In fact my A.java is `class A{ public static Integer age = 30; static{ age = 22; }}` in my project. and the age property in my project is a custom object. So can I hava static block in Kotlin?

Comment: You can't have static blocks in Kotlin if you refuse to create an `object`.

Comment: If you consider it OK to have an `object`, use `object Blabla { init { your init code here } }`

Answer (score 4):

Kotlin ***properties*** declared in a ***named object*** or a ***companion object*** have ***private*** visibility from java code

But they can be exposed using

- `@JvmField` annotation
- `lateinit` modifier
- `const` modifier

Read more about kotlin static fields [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#static-fields)

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider declaring it at the top-level outside of a (companion) object:

```
var age = 30

class A {
    ...
}
```

This can be accessed from Java like a static class `AKt` containing `age`. You can also add `@file:JvmName("A")` at the top of the file containing `age` to get rid of the Kt suffix and access it via `A.age`.

Comment: sorry, if I do it with your suggestion, I must invoke `A.getAge()` rather than `A.age`.